# SwiftUI TabView with PageTabViewStyle rotation issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, pagetabviewstyle

I am having some issues when rotating a paging TabView.  I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.systemGroupedBackground)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            TabView {
                ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user  in
                    CardView(user: user)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))

        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            Image("someImage")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .padding([.top, .horizontal], 30)
        .padding([.bottom], 50)
    }
}
```

When I rotate to landscape and then start to page through the cards I notice some of the cards are still in Portrait with the content clipped despite the fact that the device is in landscape.  It seems to happen randomly and only effect a few cards.  I tried to listen for rotation and then toggle a state var to see if the view would redraw correctly after rotation but it makes no difference whatsoever.  Not sure if this is a bug or how to rectify.

Comment: Could yo provide the code for `CardView` as well?

Comment: Have edited to include the CardView which just displays an image

Comment: try .scaledToFill() instead of .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) and add .clipped() to ZStack

Comment: Hey @alionthego did you ever managed to solve this issue? I'm facing the same.

Comment: I haven’t found any consistent solution.